# Partially hiding an email address with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I have found two topics which at first appear to answer my query but they only seem to get me part-way to a solution. Using them I have got to where I am. So it's not a duplicate!

I want to replace all but the first character in the name part and domain part of an email address with an asterisk:

**eg**

> g******@g****.com or g******@g****.co.uk

**code:**

```
$email2 = preg_replace('/(?<=.).(?=.*@)/', '*', $email);
$email3 = preg_replace('/(?<=@.)[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=(?:[.]|$))/', '*', $email2);
```

which is almost there but gives me **g******@g*.com** rather than **g******@g*****.com**

Can anyone help me with the regex please?

Comment: Graham if someone gave you the answer you are looking for, don't forget to accept that answer so people know the question is resolved.

Comment: @vivek-mdu I did explain why it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
$email = preg_replace('/(?:^|@).\K|\.[^@]*$(*SKIP)(*F)|.(?=.*?\.)/', '*', $email);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT0lX3/2)

This will turn `great@gmail.com` into `g*****@g*****.com` and

`myemail@gmail.co.uk` will become `m*******@g*****.co.uk`

and `test.test@gmail.com` into `t*********@g*****.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
^.\K|.(?=.*@)|@.\K|\..*(*SKIP)(*F)|.(?=.*\.)
```

You can try this.Replace by `*`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/20

Comment: That's great. Thanks. I have been tearing my hair out trying to find a solution.

Comment: `myemail@gmail.co.uk` will be replaced by `m*******@g********.uk` I believe op wants to keep `m*******@g*****.co.uk`